# Next.js 13 State Not Updating on Scroll

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, scroll, state, next.js13

I'm facing an issue with my code where the state doesn't seem to update on scroll. I'm currently using Next.js version **^13.4.19**. When I include a `console.log()` inside the `useEffect`, I'm not getting any output, and the state remains stuck at its default value of **0**.

*Can someone help me figure out what might be causing this problem and how to resolve it?*

**@/components/navbar.tsx**

```js
'use client';

...

const Navbar = (navbarProps: navbarProps) => {
    const [offsetTop, setOffsetTop] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScrollEvent = () => {
            setOffsetTop(window.scrollY);
        };

        handleScrollEvent();

        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScrollEvent, {passive: true});

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScrollEvent);
        };
    }, [offsetTop]);
    
    ...
    
}
```

Comment: put log inside `handleScrollEvent` and check if it gets called, if it does, then `offsetTop` should change - and remove `offsetTop` dependency you aren't using it anyway

Comment: I removed `offsetTop` as a dependency, I added a log inside `handleScrollEvent` and i get nothing @GiorgiMoniava

Comment: `typeof window` is `undefined` even if i wrote `'use client'`. I created a new project with latest versions of all the libraries in which i added this component and still no difference. I use this component (Navbar) in a `page.tsx`. If i write a log in the body of the component it get printed in the sever console. What am I missing? @GiorgiMoniava

Comment: if i do this `export const DynamicNavbar = dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(Navbar), {ssr: false,})` and make the `page.tsx` async it works but in my main project i have an async `page.tsx` with inside a component that is not async that contains the `DynamicNavbar` component, how i make it work in this scenario?